# iOS4 app functionality and launch of other apps

Tags: ios4

I want to develop an app that can open other native apps that I have downloaded from the iTunes store. Can that be done?

If so, when I close the second app, where will I then return to, the desktop or the app I opened it through?

Answer (score 0):

If the other apps support Custom URL schemes you can launch them:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"customappurlscheme://www.stackoverflow.com?question=123"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```